# How to check and req storage permissions in ionic?

Tags: javascript, permissions, ionic2, ionic3

I searched about check/req permissions and I found 2 plugins:

1st : android permission

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/

2nd : diagnostic

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/

I checked the second one but it show me error when I wrote EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Then I checked the 1st one but its not work .. here is my codes :

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then( (result) => {
            //console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission)
    },err => {
            this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(_=>{
        targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+ "download/"+moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmsss")+".jpg";
        fileTransfer.download(image.img, targetPath, true).then((entry) => {
            alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {
            alert("please check application permissions");
        });
    });
});
```

So which plugin works in ionic  and how ?

Answer (score 2):

solved problem by using the 1st plugin and this way:

```
download(image) {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
let targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+ "download/"+moment().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmsss")+".jpg";
fileTransfer.download(image.img, targetPath, true).then((entry) => {
  alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {
        this.checkPermissions();
    });
}

checkPermissions(){
    this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
        [
            this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
            this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ]
    );
}
```